# Error reading .xlsx files. The script was shared, I haven´t modified it. I make sure to set the working directory and files

Tags: r, xlsx

```
> marco = read.xlsx(paste0(rutadatos, "MarcoDeMuestreo.xlsx"))
Error in read.xlsx.default(paste0(rutadatos, "MarcoDeMuestreo.xlsx")) : 
  File does not exist.
> rutadatos
[1] "F:/IECM/COTECORA/2a_Reunion_trabajo_202024/marcoyplan2021/marcoyplan/"
> list.files()
[1] "Alcaldias.xlsx"       "APP_2021"             "MarcoDeMuestreo.xlsx" "marcoyplan2021.Rproj"
[5] "Muestra_2021"         "PlanDeMuestreo.xlsx" 
> getwd()
[1] "F:/IECM/COTECORA/2a_Reunion_trabajo_202024/marcoyplan2021"
>
```

I tried checking the working directory and listing files, but I have the same error, files does not exist

Comment: Please properly tag this question.  If, in fact you are using Rstudio that tag should be present.

Comment: If your working directory is already in that specific folder, you don't need to specify from there where the location of the file is. From R's perspective, you're repeating the path twice.

Comment: Your path, `rutadatos` points to a subdirectory (`marcoyplan/`) within the working directory. But the `list.files()` shows that there is no such folder and that the files is at `"F:/IECM/COTECORA/2a_Reunion_trabajo_202024/marcoyplan2021"`.  Try `marco = read.xlsx("MarcoDeMuestreo.xlsx")`